# Ollydbg not displaying full info

Tags: ollydbg

[image]

Ollydbg isn't displaying the full info for me sometimes. (I want to see the function names like on the left side)

How can I get it to display the function names all the time?

Answer (score 4):

OllyDbg, just as other debuggers, needs symbol information in order to retrieve function names. Such information is usually kept inside a Program Database (PDB) file or DBG file which produced by the compiler. 
PDB files are used by developers to debug their program and commonly removed from the binary before it distributed to the client, so most chances is that you won't find debug symbols inside most of the real-world binaries.

Ollydbg searches for the pdb file in the debugee's folder. If your pdb file isn't in the folder of the debugged program I believe you can drag and drop the pdb file to Ollydbg and it'll load it.

One exception, for example, is exported functions of a libraries that shipped with their names so debuggers don't need symbol files in order to detect them.

[Here you can read more about Symbols and Symbol Files.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbols-and-symbol-files)